# Best way to eliminate columns with only one value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to build a function to eliminate from my dataset the columns with only one value. I used this function:

```
def oneCatElimination(dataframe):
    columns=dataframe.columns.values
    for column in columns:
        if len(dataframe[column].value_counts().unique())==1:
             del dataframe[column]   
     return dataframe
```

the problem is that the function eliminates even column with more the one distinct value, i.e. a index column with integer number..

Comment: please show us a case where your function does not work as intended.

Answer (score 14):

Just

```
df.dropna(thresh=2, axis=1)
```

will work. No need for anything else. It will keep all columns with 2 or more non-NA values (controlled by the value passed to `thresh`). The `axis` kwarg will let you work with rows or columns. It is rows by default, so you need to pass `axis=1` explicitly to work on columns (I forgot this at the time I answered, hence this edit). See [`dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for more information.

Comment: Plus 1 for finding a batteries-included approach.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of assumptions went into this:

- Null/NA values don't count
- You need multiple non-NA values to keep a column
- Those values need to be different in some way (e.g., a column full of 1's and only 1's should be dropped)

All that said, I would use a `select` statement on the columns.

If you start with this dataframe:

```
import pandas

N = 15
df = pandas.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.loc[2, 'A'] = 23
df.loc[3, 'B'] = 52
df.loc[4, 'B'] = 36
df.loc[5, 'C'] = 11
df.loc[6, 'C'] = 11
df.loc[7, 'D'] = 43
df.loc[8, 'D'] = 63
df.loc[9, 'D'] = 97

df
```

Which creates:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   23  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN   52  NaN  NaN
4  NaN   36  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN   11  NaN
6  NaN  NaN   11  NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN   43
8  NaN  NaN  NaN   63
9  NaN  NaN  NaN   97
```

Given my assumptions above, columns A and C should be dropped since A only has one value and both of C's values are the same. You can then do:

```
df.select(lambda c: df[c].dropna().unique().shape[0] > 1, axis=1)
```

And that gives me:

```
     B    D
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3   52  NaN
4   36  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN
7  NaN   43
8  NaN   63
9  NaN   97
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for both text and numbers:

```
for col in dataframe:
    if(len(dataframe.loc[:,col].unique()) == 1):
        dataframe.pop(col)
```

Note: This will remove the columns having only one value from the original dataframe.